# Is it possible to use a react Hook Component inside a Class?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I wanted to implement Dark Mode in my app, I built all of it with Classes and Components and when I tried to implement react-native-dark-mode I got an error that I am not able to use Hook in a class. It would take a lot of time to rewrite everything.

ORIGINAL

```
import { useDarkMode } from 'react-native-dark-mode'

function Component() {
    const isDarkMode = useDarkMode()
    return <View style={{ backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? 'black' : 'white' }} />
}
```

But I want something like:

```
import { useDarkMode } from 'react-native-dark-mode'

class Home extends React.Component ... 
render() {
    const isDarkMode = useDarkMode()
    return (<View style={{ backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? 'black' : 'white' }} />)
}
```

Comment: you found any work around for this other than this answer

Answer (score 0):

Hooks cannot be used directly from a class component but you can introduce a single functional component that will extract the value you need from the hook:

```
function ViewWithTheme() {
    const isDarkMode = useDarkMode()
    return <View style={{ backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? 'black' : 'white' }} />
}

class Home extends React.Component {
    // ...
    render() {
        return <ViewWithTheme />
    }
}
```